# How to refresh FilterUIProvider after loading GridFilterSettings?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

In our software, it is possible to save the gridsettings, which also includes the **filtersettings**.

For providing nice filtering, we are using the **FilterUIProvider** of Infragistics, which shows the filtering criterias, like in the following picture (I apologize, it's German):

[image: figure 1: FilterUIProvider of Infragistics]

However, if I try to load the FilterSettings from the database into the grid, the **Checked Items of the FilterUIProvider do not change (!)**

This is the codesnippet I am having (Loading the FilterSettings):

```
    For Each FilterSetting As GridFilter In CurrentVorlage.VorlageData.GridFilterSettings
        If Not FilterSetting.Key.Equals(.Key) Then Continue For
        Dim cond As New FilterCondition
        cond.CompareValue = FilterSetting.CompareValue 'value from database
        cond.ComparisionOperator = CType(FilterSetting.ComparisionOperator.FilterComparisionOperator) 'value from database
        e.Layout.Bands(0).ColumnFilters(.Key).FilterConditions.Add(cond)
        e.Layout.Bands(0).ColumnFilters(.Key).LogicalOperator = CType(FilterSetting.LogicalOperator, FilterLogicalOperator)
    Next
```

**The rows in the grid are filtered out as expected, though.** 
The only problem is that the FilterUIProvider seems deaf to the filtersettings changes.
So if the user clicks on the Filter again, all items are unchecked.
And if the User checks something else on the filter, the FilterSettings are gone, too.

**What am I missing that the items are checked / unchecked according to the GridFilterSettings?**

I have browsed through the internet, the Infragistics Help Site but unfortunately I haven't found anything, really.
Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** I also posted the same question on [Infragistics Forum](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/85525/426645.aspx#426645), where I provided an example application.

Comment: A side note: comments in VB.NET are denoted with a single quote `'`, rather than `//` like in C#. Regarding your question, did you consider asking Infragistics support? I have not dealt with Infragistics before, but other vendors generally provide support for their products, and such specific questions are usually answered in no time.

Comment: @Neolisk Thanks for your sidenote. Yes, I also posted something on their support site. Take a look at my EDIT in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to update the infragistics version to **2010.3**, as pointed out by Mike Saltzman:

> Your sample is working fine for me. When I run the sample the first
>   time, it comes up with two filters (Blanks) and 36. When I drop down
>   the Filter UI, those are the two items checked on the list. I tried
>   changing the filtered items and clicking the Save button, then
>   stopping and re-running the app, and once again, it's working fine.
>   The items I selected are still filtered and they are still checked on
>   the list when I drop it down.
>
> So my guess is that this is just a bug in the version you are using
>   and you need to get the latest service release

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/85525/427503.aspx#427503